# Which directory is taking up the most space

Tags: shell, filenames, disk-usage, jenkins

Jenkins has stopped building and I can see from df:
that /var is maxed. Following this I can see the culprit is /var/lib/jenkins

```
52K     alternatives
...
4.0K    games
2.3G    jenkins   <--this one
4.0K    logrotate.status
...
12M     yum
2.4G    total
```

However, when I enter the jenkins dir to see which folder is consuming most of this 2.3GB, there are some strange results:

```
$ sudo du -csh *
16K     config.xml
0       Connection Activity monitoring to slaves.log
0       Download metadata.log
0       Fingerprint cleanup.log
7.3M    fingerprints
4.0K    hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet.xml
4.0K    hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml
4.0K    hudson.scm.CVSSCM.xml
4.0K    hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.xml
4.0K    hudson.tasks.Ant.xml
4.0K    hudson.tasks.Mailer.xml
4.0K    hudson.tasks.Maven.xml
4.0K    hudson.tasks.Shell.xml
4.0K    hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger.xml
4.0K    identity.key.enc
4.0K    jenkins.diagnostics.ooom.OutOfOrderBuildMonitor
4.0K    jenkins.model.ArtifactManagerConfiguration.xml
4.0K    jenkins.model.DownloadSettings.xml
4.0K    jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml
4.0K    jenkins.mvn.GlobalMavenConfig.xml
4.0K    jenkins.security.QueueItemAuthenticatorConfiguration.xml
160M    jobs
4.0K    nodeMonitors.xml
12K     Out of order build detection.log
41M     plugins
4.0K    proxy.xml
4.0K    queue.xml.bak
4.0K    secret.key
0       secret.key.not-so-secret
32K     secrets
1.1M    updates
8.0K    userContent
12K     users
4.0K    Workspace clean-up.log
209M    total
```

From 2.3GB to 209M. Can anyone explain this so I can create some space? I've deleted the Jenkins workspaces from the web frontend but still see this result.

Comment: I'm seeing that du -ch (instead of du -csh) is returning more results I need. If anyone can explain this I can accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With this command,

```
sudo du -csh *
```

you are missing hidden directories, i.e. `*` expands to all names starting with anything but a dot (`.`). That means all directory names starting with a dot are not passed to the `du` command and their size is not taken into account.

In most situations, adding `.??*` to the parameters would fit the needs :

```
sudo du -csh .??* *
```

The extra `.??*` is expanding to all names starting with a dot and having more than two characters. The goal is to exclude `..`, i.e. the parent directory from the arguments.

Hypothetical files and directories like `.a` would still be missed, and those starting with a dash (`-`) would be at best ignored and at worst trigger an error.

If you have files or directories names starting with a dash or names starting with a dot followed by a single character, this enhanced version will properly report all directory sizes:

```
sudo du -csh -- .[^.] .??* *
```

Here the `--` is telling `du` to take arguments starting with a dash as names, not options and `.[^.]` is adding to the processed names all file and directories starting with a dot followed by any single character but a dot. This encompass all possible names for files and directories.

Several shells provide custom workarounds to these naming issues:

**`bash`**:

```
shopt -s dotglob
sudo du -csh -- *
```

**`zsh`**:

```
sudo du -csh -- *(D)
```

**`ksh93`**:

```
FIGNORE='@(.|..)'
sudo du -csh -- *
```

Comment: ... and please don't try `.*` as you would go through `..` (which will take a significantly larger amount of time).

Comment: @JohnWHSmith, not if you're using `zsh` (or `fish`) which have fixed that bug. In `zsh`, you'd use `du -csh -- *(D)` though to include dot file. You also need the `--` as otherwise a file called `-s` for instance wouldn't be accounted for.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas This shell always has something to surprise me... I'm guessing a more *portable* way to do this would be to use `find` and `du`: `find -maxdepth 1 | du -csh`.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith, more like `find . ! -name . -prune -exec du -csh {} +`. `-maxdepth` is not portable, `find -print` output is generally not post-processable and `du` doesn't read its stdin.

Comment: Thanks. As I say in the comment beneath my question, I'm seeing that du -ch (instead of du -csh) with no other args is returning the results I need. Isn't this a little over complicated or am I missing something?

Comment: @TenLeftFingers, `du -ch` gives you all levels of sub-directories. The GNU implementation of `du` has a `--max-depth` option though for limiting the depth at which you want to see the reports.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas correct. So I want the full totals without printing the subdirectory contents. I'm not sure what jlliagre 's answer adds to this.

Comment: @TenLeftFingers, in `du *`, the _shell_ expands the `*` into a list of files but excludes the hidden ones. Your missing disk space is either in those hidden ones or in a file or directory called `-s` or any option or combination of options supported by your `du` implementation.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas, that answers my question and offers a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily the answer you're looking for, but something good to know about is:

```
sudo du -max /var/lib/jenkins | sort -n
```

That's probably one of the commands I use most often for this sort of thing.  The "-a" includes total directory size (so you'll see a directory full of small files as one big directory in the final output, as well as seeing all the files), and the -x keeps it in in one filesystem.  Using -m rather than -h makes it arguably harder to read, but using a fixed unit facilitates a more portable numeric sort (as in, still works when you don't have a pretty new sort command which supports the -h modifier).

Answer (score 1):

Try out [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu). This is an ncurses-based mc-like directory browser that will let you see which directories are most occupied and optionally delete the ones you're not interested in, as seen on this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @TenLeftFingers: if you think that this answers your problem to a bigger degree than a currently accepted answer, please consider accepting this instead.

Comment: The accepted answer (unwieldy as the commands are) uses tools installed by default on all our servers and explains those so I will need to use that in practise. I have reduced it to a much simpler command, as per my comment but it did answer my question, technically speaking.

Answer (score 0):

There are also nice graphical tools to help figure out what in is taking up lots of space in a directory.

I like [Filelight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filelight) which is part of KDE.  Here it is exploring */var/cache* on my computer.  The green and the yellow are related to *apt*, the red is *java*, and the magenta is *pbuilder*.

[image: filelight]

The inner circles the immediate subdirectories and they are broken out into smaller pieces in the outer circles.   This tool makes it very easy to browse around and see what is taking up lots of space -- not just large files, but large collections of small files as well.

Comment: I'm familiar with this great tool, but our servers are naturally headless.